# How to cope with platform fragmentation, is device tree the answer?

Tags: x86, arm, cross-platform, embedded-linux, device-tree

My task is to implement a custom layer with fixed names for things like Ethernet and LEDs.

It needs to be the same on x86 and ARM devices. So the *Power LED* and *eth1* is always the same for the applications, but are not connected to the same hardware pins. From my point of view I can do this on ARM with Device Tree assignments. But can I use the device tree on x86 based boards to do this? Is it good practice?

Background Information:
Targets: wide range of embedded Linux Boards, Buildsystem: Buildroot, Custom Linux Kernel Versions, no Linux distribution, Busybox running on top

Comment: One point that speaks against the Device Tree is that I have boards which are running old kernel Versions like 3.2, I know that it might be possible to use it none the less. But with changes in the Bootloader and Kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - Device tree is not the answer you are looking for.  There are many ways to do this depending on your ultimate needs.

---

*Device Tree* is inherited from the PowerPC.  It is not an interface to user-space.  It is intended to provide a data driven customization of board layouts for a given CPU/SOC family.  For instance, there are many [TI OMAP devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMAP)<sup>See devices in tables</sup> each of which has different chips connected to the CPU (different Ethernet MII/RMII,etc) with various pin, clock, power, etc configurations.  Each has the same TI OMAP SOC so the code to configure this is know for all of them.  *Device Tree* is an input for the board to configure the SOC to use the hardware.  Device drivers may have hooks to alter behaviour when a particular SOC (or board) is found.

Device tree is a way for a boot loader to tell the kernel what hardware is present and should be configured.

---

There are various methods you can use to talk to user space.  Some are the same underlying thing with different use cases...

1. Make a system new call.
2. *netlink*
3. File system (device file)
4. *procfs*
5. *sysfs*
6. *debugfs*
7. Signals
8. udev/mdev
9. User-space GPIO
10. `select` (file/socket)

Items 3-6 are all basically the same.  Generally, files are synchronous.  Ie, if you have a PIN output they are fine as you can just write to them from user-space.  However, say you have an input pin like a custom card (daughter board) present/insert.  Maybe you have some RS-232 cable connected or head-phone insert pin?  With a file interface, you must poll them (or you need to have *inotify* etc support in your kernel code).  *netlink* is a way to provide messages from the kernel to user-space.  It makes sense if your pin can be connect to a system interrupt (in any case).

*mdev* and *udev* use *netlink* to tell user-space about PCI, USB, etc hardware being connected/disconnected.  You can use a similar scheme for GPIO.  You just make a link between */sys/class/output/led1* and */dev/my_company/power_led* with a mdev/udev script.

Personally, I would want to put the naming in user space and not the kernel.  What is *eth1* for instance?  Maybe you want a *diagnostic* and *main* communication Ethernet port?  Hardware might not populate *diagnostic* port at some point to make the BOM cheaper.  Then maybe *eth1* is *eth0*?

Comment: Thank you versy much for sharing this.

Comment: 8) udev/mdev are out of questions since I already had lots of trouble creating consistent rules with different devices involved (might be caused through hardware as well). Your last point is what I am after, the developers need a Debug_Ethernet_Interface which is in Hardware connected to anything from eth0/1/2,usb0 or something virtual and also the abstraction of something like a status LED. I am not sure if I can cover everythig with something like sysfs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [sysfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).

For example you can access network inteface information via `/sys/class/net/eth0/`. For specific peripheral you can provide your own kernel objects which provides a stable name.

This already keeps x86 / ARM difference to a minimum for applications. I'm thinking for example wpa_supplicant or most of the init level initialization scripts.

Comment: This answer is kept short, but does have a point. I would have accept it, but artless noise did put a lot of thought into his/her answer.